# Handling Java 8 Optional with Spring cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

Considering a service class that can insert and retrieve objects and use Spring cache abstraction, how can I annotate methods in a way that an Optional is returned?

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "itemCache";      

    @Override
    @Cacheable(CACHE_NAME)
    public Optional<Item> findById(Long id) {
        // access the repository to retrieve the item
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_NAME, key = "#item.id")
    public Item insertItem(Item item) {
        ...
    }

}
```

In the above example, a `ClassCastException` is thrown because `insertItem` puts an `Item` instance in the cache, and `findById` expects an `Optional` that may contain an `Item` instance.

Comment: We don't support `Optional` yet. I guess we could do that, please create an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have just created https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14230

Comment: Wow, I am on holiday right now and Juergen already implemented it. That was fast ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Just a follow-up on the comment to give a definitive answer to this one. We do as of Spring Framework 4.3 RC2

Comment: Do we have support for Stream ?

Comment: That's a different question (and a totally different thing). The answer is no.

Comment: Thanks Sir Nicoll.